# MARIADB overlap function for time periods

Tags: sql, mariadb, temporal-tables

We have multiple, connected tables that change over time and we need to do
queries where we want all information over a certain time period.

Let's assume our database has these two tables tb1 and tb2 with the  following
corresponding columns and values in them:

```
tb1
pk  fk  start   end
1   1   2020-01 2021-01
1   2   2021-01 inf

tb2
pk_refd val start   end
1       1   2000-01 2022-01
1       2   2022-01 inf
2       4   2000-01 inf
```

When I do the following query:

```
SELECT tb1.pk, tb1.fk, tb2.val,
    tb1.start_timestamp AS tb1_START, tb1.end_timestamp AS tb1_End,
    tb2.start_timestamp AS tb2_START, tb2.end_timestamp AS tb2_End
FROM
    tb1 FOR SYSTEM_TIME
        FROM '2000-01-01 00:00:00' TO '2030-01-01 00:00:00',
    tb2 FOR SYSTEM_TIME
        FROM '2000-01-01 00:00:00' TO '2030-01-01 00:00:00'
WHERE tb1.fk = tb2.pk_refd;
```

I get:

```
pk  fk  val tb1_START   tb1_End tb2_START   tb2_End
1   1   1   2020-01-01  2021-01-01  2000-01-01  2022-01-01
1   1   2   2020-01-01  2021-01-01  2022-01-01  2038-01-19
1   2   3   2021-01-01  2038-01-19  2000-01-01  2038-01-19
```

(I deleted the exact time and just left the date for readability)

The problem is the entry

```
pk  fk  val tb1_START   tb1_End tb2_START   tb2_End
1   1   2   2020-01-01  2021-01-01  2022-01-01  2038-01-19
```

This is not a valid reference since the time periods of the entries don't
overlap.

1. Is there some kind of overlap(period1, period2) function or some constraint,
   trigger or something I can define beforehand so queries like that don't
   return non overlapping references?
   I know I can manually check if the different start and end times of the tables
   overlap, but that becomes messy quickly as soon as there are 3 or more tables
   all connected in a row (tb1.fk=tb2.fk, tb2.fk2=tb3.fk2, ...).
2. Is e.g. MariaDB a good choice for this scenario?
   Is there any better database for this scenario
   that would also work (can also be NOSQL)?

Create table statemets:

```
CREATE TABLE tb1 (
    pk int,
    fk int,
    start_timestamp TIMESTAMP(6) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START,
    end_timestamp TIMESTAMP(6) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(start_timestamp, end_timestamp),
    PRIMARY KEY (pk, start_timestamp)
) WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING;

CREATE TABLE tb2 (
    pk_refd int,
    val varchar(255),
    start_timestamp TIMESTAMP(6) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START,
    end_timestamp TIMESTAMP(6) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(start_timestamp, end_timestamp),
    PRIMARY KEY(pk_refd, start_timestamp)
) WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING;

-- add foreign Key constraints
ALTER TABLE tb1
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_fk
FOREIGN KEY (fk)
REFERENCES tb2(pk_refd);


-- insert data
-- Beginning of Time
SET timestamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO tb2(pk_refd, val) VALUES (1, '1');
INSERT INTO tb2(pk_refd, val) VALUES (2, '3');

-- 2. point in time
SET timestamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO tb1(pk, fk) VALUES (1, 1);

-- 3. point in time
SET timestamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-01-01 00:00:00');
UPDATE tb1 SET fk = 2 WHERE pk = 1;


-- 4. point in time
SET timestamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:00:00');
Update tb2 SET val = '2' WHERE pk_refd = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, Avoid `,` (almost always0 as a join operator and use explicit inner joins.

Step 2, use a join criteria that has overlaps

So:

```
SELECT tb1.pk, tb1.fk, tb2.val,
    tb1.start_timestamp AS tb1_START, tb1.end_timestamp AS tb1_End,
    tb2.start_timestamp AS tb2_START, tb2.end_timestamp AS tb2_End
FROM
    tb1 FOR SYSTEM_TIME
        FROM '2000-01-01 00:00:00' TO '2030-01-01 00:00:00'
JOIN
    tb2 FOR SYSTEM_TIME
        FROM '2000-01-01 00:00:00' TO '2030-01-01 00:00:00'
ON tb1.fk = tb2.pk_refd
AND tb2_START <= tb1_End
AND tb1_Start <= tb2_End
```

So yes, relational databases like MariaDB are good for this.

Comment: Which would mean for multiple tables doing some kind of 
`ON tb1.fk = tb2.pk_refd
AND tb2.fk2 = tb3.fk2
AND GREATEST(tb1_Start, tb2_Start, tb3_Start) < LEAST(tb1_End, tb2_End, tb3_End)`
Is necessary?

Comment: I tend to think if the relationship is tb2 -> tb3 the overlap between only those tables is an added condition. You might be getting too much with the `GREATEST`/`LEAST` approach. I'm also assuming that its an `[INNER] JOIN` rather than outer. Outer joins would leave `start_timestamp` values with `NULL` making overlaps needing a different criteria.